# GCM push notification does not work correctly when using Wifi network

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I successfully integrated my app for receiving push notification using GCM. Its working correctly, I just saw a strange behavior while receiving push notification on one of my android set which is using my wifi network, in the same time others whose are using EDGE or 3G network are receiving notifications correctly. When I try to switch off and switch on the wifi, it receives the pending notification.

I tried opening the ports which normally used by GCM i.e 5228,5229 and 5230 in my router's firewall however with no success.

NB: After seeing this, I tried to configure the app for Parse API and its working as same as GCM so I think it depends upon the network packet receiving or something.

Comment: I dont think so. Might be some Restriction into your WiFi becoz i already work on this and its working fine in all the Networks

Answer (score 1):

I believe, what you're facing is a known issue about TCP connection between GCM servers and your handset is timing out because of inactivity. Network devices (like your Wi-Fi router, your ISP hardware, etc.) between your handset and GCM servers could kill the TCP connection if no packets are sent every now and then.

There are some workarounds for this which you might try. For example, there are [apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andqlimax.pushfixer.noroot) on Google Play that modify the default Android behavior and make it update this connection more often, increasing chances that it will not timeout. You could try them and see if it fixes the problem for you.

Comment: Okay Haspemulator, can we use some kind of code which in background used by the above said apps so that we can make the connection alive ourselves?

Comment: I can confirm this. My GCM notifications were instantaneous through wifi at one time. I changed ISP and switched to a cable modem/router and the delay can be 15 minutes with the same app that worked immediately before.

Comment: @NickT is there a work around I can try to overcome this type of issue?

Comment: @Saty, I haven't found one, but then again I haven't looked that hard, as for my purposes it's more important that messages via 3G are quick.

Comment: You don't have access to that connection on Android, OS manages it for you, and it sends those keep-alive packets on a pre-defined timescale (something like every 30 minutes on 3G and every 15 minutes on Wi-Fi). What is in your reach is to send notifications to your app, say, every minute or so.

Comment: @NickT I tried your second option like I set a cron on my server which will send a blank notification to all devices to avoid connection time-out. However it does not reach either..

Comment: When I try to send many push notification one by one in like 30 seconds interval, some reaches and some do not however sometimes they reach later... is GCM's push notification unreliable then?

Comment: If you send a lot of messages, you might face the throttling by GCM servers: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#throttling